# SSRS: Excel-Rendering always created an empty Column

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a strange problem with the SSRS-Excel Renderer:
As soon as I create a Table, it can be empty, with more than one Column, at the most right column, an empty Excel-Column shows up:

[image]

In the example, I just putted a plain Table into the RDLC, added the hardcoded values 1 to 4, and you can see, there is the 'C`Column pretty small, but without any values anywhere in it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding this is possible only if Report width is greater than tablix width,

Just Make sure you have same width for both Report & Tablix, Report width is in pt but tablix Size.width in inch.. so use any conversion and set same width for both.

Roughly 1 inch= 72 pt

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the problem was a bit simplified: I have 5 Tablixes right to eachother, and now every SSRS-Tablix creates such an empty Excel-Column.